# Find input value of a class with distinct id?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the JavaScript code to get all IDs of "state" class.
I want to get all the input value of the class state.
How to get all states class of the class India using JavaScript?

```
 function get_states(){
    var category = document.formy.category.value;
    var date_from = document.formy.date_from.value;
    var date_to = document.formy.date_to.value;
    var no_of_states = document.querySelectorAll(".states").length;
     var from = Date.parse(date_from);
     var to = Date.parse(date_to);
     var state_name = ["karnataka", "maharashtra", "bihar"]; 
     if (to > from) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= state_name.length - 1; i++) {
            document.write(state_name[i]);
            document.write("<br>");
        }
     }
     else
        document.write('back');
   }
```

I want to get all the input IDs value of class state.

Here is HTML:

```
    <form action="search_content.php" method="post" name="formy">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="custom-select" name="category" required="required">
                  <option value="0">Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input type="date" name="date_from" required="required"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input type="date" name="date_to" required="required"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="get_states()"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="india">
                <div class="states" id="karnataka">
                    <input type="hidden" name="karnataka" value="2018-02-02">
                    <p>ABCD</p>
                </div>
                <div class="states" id="maharastra">
                    <input type="hidden" name="maharastra" value="2018-06-02">
                    <p>ABCD</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How do I get the all-state input value? Please explain.

Comment: You really should ask the question in the body, not the title. And please edit your question and format the HTML correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML you posted is not formatted so hard to decipher but, for the general case, you could do:

```
let ids = [];
let els = document.getElementsByClassName('state')
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    ids.push(els[i].id);
}
```

Comment: let is like var?

Comment: yes, but `let` is limited to the block it is used in whereas `var` leaks to the global scope or defining function